# Objective C UItableView header custom view black

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am creating a custom view for my header and it only shows up as a black rectangle. 
The code for the tableviewcontroller is:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    head* headerView = [[head alloc]init];
    headerView.name=[sectionList objectAtIndex:section];
    [headerView setNeedsDisplay];
    return headerView;
}
```

where head is the custom view with a drawrect function:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:125 green:125 blue:125 alpha:.5]];
    bounds = [self bounds];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGSize titleSize=CGSizeFromString(self.name);
    CGRect titleRect={CGPointMake(10, 10),titleSize};
    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:titleRect];

    [title setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [title setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [title setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Trebuchet MS" size: 14.0f]];
    [title setText:self.name];
    [self addSubview:title];

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 80, 168, 206, 0.5);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(titleRect.origin.x, 0,20, 20));
    }
```

Also when I try to set the name in the viewController (see above). The name remains null.

When I tried to do it without a custom UIView. This time it only showed a white view:

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,        self.tableView.bounds.size.width,40.0f)];
    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:71 green:71 blue:71 alpha:.5]];
    UIImage *reps = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"test" ofType: @"png"]];
    CGSize titleSize=CGSizeFromString([sectionList objectAtIndex:section]);
    CGRect titleRect={CGPointMake(0, 0),titleSize};
    UILabel *groupTitle = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:titleRect];
    [groupTitle setText:[sectionList objectAtIndex:section]];
    [headerView addSubview:groupTitle];
    UIImageView* repsView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:reps];
    [headerView addSubview:repsView];
    return headerView;
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create headerView by providing frame, for example:

```
head* headerView = [[head alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 40.0f)];
```

After that make sure you implemented table view delegate for table header height:

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return 40.0f;
}
```

You should consider create custom view without overriding `drawRect:` method because this is very CPU expensive.

Comment: It still is black, however now the setter for the property nam now works.